# How to use this PCB terminal?

Tags: pcb, wire-terminals

I'm wiring up a home EV charger which has this PCB terminal for the data connection.

Can anyone tell me how to connect the cable?

[image: 45 degree terminal block]

Comment: To where would you wire that? It does not look like it is for data connection. Please hire a licenced electrician capable of legally doing the installation in legal and safe way, so your car or house does not burn down.

Comment: If you need to ask, you are unqualified for such an installation. Call an electrician before you electrocute yourself, anyone else or burn a building down.

Comment: The labelling on the PCB (WIRED CT, CT1, CT2, CT3) leads me to believe that this set of terminals are inputs for **C**urrent **T**ransformers. You're not going to get any data out of them.

Answer (score 3):

These look like a Wago Cage Clamp terminal. Insert a small flat blade screwdriver into the top slot and lever gently upwards. This opens the clamp so you can insert the wire into the bottom entry. Then gently remove the lifting force and remove the screwdriver. The wire should be securely clamped. Rinse and repeat.

I would expect the equipment installation instructions would outline this process.

According to the picture, those terminals are for current transformers, not data connections. I’d suggest you refer to the manufacturer’s installation instructions.